# (Animation Nodes) How do I get an object to follow a spline without rotating along it?

Tags: animation-nodes, splines

Fairly simple question but I'm new to animation nodes and don't know how to do this. I want an object to follow a spline using the Follow Spline Action, but maintain its rotation. Basically like unchecking the "follow" box in the curve data, but with nodes. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to apply the action and a transform output with the rotation you want.

[image: Follow Spline]